# Delete older device contact backups on Google

Tags: contacts, backup, google, google-contacts

Google has a feature to restore contacts that can be accessed from Settings - Google - Set up & restore - Restore contacts. This screen shows "Google Contacts" and "Device backup".

[image]

I want to delete older device backups.

I can't seem to find out online anywhere that is specific to this issue.

Comment: I haven't experimented with this, but maybe [Back up & sync device contacts](https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/9423168) is related.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com).
2. Sign in the account where you want to delete old contacts.
3. Choose contact(s) by 'check mark sign' before contacts name.
4. Click 'more' from above drop down menu, there you'll get delete option.

It's done.

**In case you have two different Google accounts added to device** and one is having your old contacts then you can disable syncing of contacts of that particular account without deleting contacts.

Go to Settings and search for 'Google account' in search tab, or alternatively, open **Settings → Cloud and accounts/accounts → click Google**

There you will see list of all connected Google accounts. Now, simply click the account you want to disable auto syncing of any particular option, such as contacts.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Doesn't remove them

Answer (score 1):

I know your question is 3 years old now but I had more or less the same problem of not knowing where they were.The backups are stored in Google Drive under storage ([see this for how to get at them](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6305834?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)) and once you delete them there than your contacts backup is deleted too. I hope this helps.